# Как сделать, чтобы from_unixtime(checkdate) возвращал 0, если checkdate равен 0

Tags: unix, mysql, linux

Мне нужно выбрать абсолютно всех пользователей с датой проверки. Выводить дату нужно в формате YYYY-MM-DD. У некоторых пользователей checkdate=0. У других, которые прошли проверку checkdate равен корректному timestamp'у.

Как сделать так, чтобы from_unixtime(checkdate) возвращал 0, если checkdate равен 0, и дату в формате YYYY-MM-DD в противном случае, Спасибо.

**p.s.** Сделать это одним запросом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select if(checkdate=0,0,from_unixtime(checkdate)) as checkdate
```

если конечно checkdate действительно может быть равен именно нулю